# Getting an empty list of services from a valid OWLS document

Tags: web-services, semantic-web, owl

I'm struggling with an abandoned java library (with a down maven repository)  to work with [OWLS](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2004/SUBM-OWL-S-20041122/) called [owls-api](http://on.cs.unibas.ch/owls-api/).  I'm trying to get the list of services from an OWLS document:

```java
OWLKnowledgeBase kb = OWLFactory.createKB();        
OWLIndividualList<Service> services = kb.readAllServices("http://127.0.0.1/services/1.1/BookPrice.owls");
        System.out.println(services.toString());
```

I keep getting an empty `services` list, **Why** ?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<rdf:RDF  xmlns:owl       = "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:rdfs      = "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:rdf       = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:service   = "http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Service.owl#"
xmlns:process   = "http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Process.owl#"
xmlns:profile    = "http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Profile.owl#"
xmlns:grounding = "http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Grounding.owl#"

xml:base        = "http://127.0.0.1/services/1.1/BookFinder.owls">

<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://127.0.0.1/ontology/Service.owl" />
<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://127.0.0.1/ontology/Process.owl" />
<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://127.0.0.1/ontology/Profile.owl" />
<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://127.0.0.1/ontology/Grounding.owl" />
<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://127.0.0.1/ontology/books.owl" />
</owl:Ontology>

<service:Service rdf:ID="TITLE_BOOK_SERVICE">
<service:presents rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_PROFILE"/>
<service:describedBy rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_PROCESS"/>
<service:supports rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_GROUNDING"/>
</service:Service>

<profile:Profile rdf:ID="TITLE_BOOK_PROFILE">
<service:isPresentedBy rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_SERVICE"/>
<profile:serviceName xml:lang="en">
BookFinder
</profile:serviceName>
<profile:textDescription xml:lang="en">
This service returns the information of a book whose title best matches the given string.
</profile:textDescription>
<profile:hasInput  rdf:resource="#_TITLE"/>
<profile:hasOutput rdf:resource="#_BOOK"/>

<profile:has_process rdf:resource="TITLE_BOOK_PROCESS" /></profile:Profile>

<!--<process:ProcessModel rdf:ID="TITLE_BOOK_PROCESS_MODEL">
    <service:describes rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_SERVICE"/>
    <process:hasProcess rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_PROCESS"/>
</process:ProcessModel>-->

<process:AtomicProcess rdf:ID="TITLE_BOOK_PROCESS">
<service:describes rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_SERVICE"/>
    <process:hasInput  rdf:resource="#_TITLE"/>
    <process:hasOutput rdf:resource="#_BOOK"/>
</process:AtomicProcess>

<process:Input rdf:ID="_TITLE">
    <process:parameterType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">http://127.0.0.1/ontology/books.owl#Title</process:parameterType>
</process:Input>

<process:Output  rdf:ID="_BOOK">
    <process:parameterType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">http://127.0.0.1/ontology/books.owl#Book</process:parameterType>
</process:Output >

<grounding:WsdlGrounding rdf:ID="TITLE_BOOK_GROUNDING">
    <service:supportedBy rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_SERVICE"/>
    <grounding:hasAtomicProcessGrounding>
      <grounding:WsdlAtomicProcessGrounding rdf:ID="TITLE_BOOK_AtomicProcessGrounding"/>
    </grounding:hasAtomicProcessGrounding>
</grounding:WsdlGrounding>

<grounding:WsdlAtomicProcessGrounding rdf:about="#TITLE_BOOK_AtomicProcessGrounding">
    <grounding:wsdlDocument rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"
    >http://127.0.0.1/wsdl/TitleBook.wsdl</grounding:wsdlDocument>
    <grounding:owlsProcess rdf:resource="#TITLE_BOOK_PROCESS"/>
    <grounding:wsdlOperation>
      <grounding:WsdlOperationRef>
        <grounding:operation rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"
        >http://127.0.0.1/wsdl/TitleBook#get_BOOK</grounding:operation>
        <grounding:portType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"
        >http://127.0.0.1/wsdl/TitleBook#TitleBookSoap</grounding:portType>
      </grounding:WsdlOperationRef>
    </grounding:wsdlOperation>
    <grounding:wsdlInputMessage rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"
    >http://127.0.0.1/wsdl/TitleBook#get_BOOKRequest</grounding:wsdlInputMessage>
    <grounding:wsdlOutputMessage rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"
    >http://127.0.0.1/wsdl/TitleBook#get_BOOKResponse</grounding:wsdlOutputMessage>
    <grounding:wsdlInput>
      <grounding:WsdlInputMessageMap>
        <grounding:owlsParameter rdf:resource="#_TITLE"/>
        <grounding:wsdlMessagePart rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"
        >http://127.0.0.1/wsdl/TitleBook#_TITLE</grounding:wsdlMessagePart>
        <grounding:xsltTransformationString>None (XSL)</grounding:xsltTransformationString>
      </grounding:WsdlInputMessageMap>
    </grounding:wsdlInput>
    <grounding:wsdlOutput>
      <grounding:WsdlOutputMessageMap>
        <grounding:owlsParameter rdf:resource="#_BOOK"/>
        <grounding:wsdlMessagePart rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"
        >http://127.0.0.1/wsdl/TitleBook#_BOOK</grounding:wsdlMessagePart>
        <grounding:xsltTransformationString>None (XSL)</grounding:xsltTransformationString>
      </grounding:WsdlOutputMessageMap>
    </grounding:wsdlOutput>
  </grounding:WsdlAtomicProcessGrounding>

</rdf:RDF>
```

(* all static files are `well` server using grizzly java web server)
Is there any alternative to this buggy library to work with `owls` files ?

### Update

https://github.com/tarrsalah/owls-example/issues/1

Comment: I've helped porting an application from owls to owl api a while ago. Owl api does not have anything dedicated for OWL-S but it's possible not much would actually be needed. I'll see if anything I did can help here.

Comment: In the meantime, you're asking for all the services for BookPrice, but the ontology you show has BookFinder as base. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'd give a whirl to a few different urls, just in case it's only a matter of getting the right one.

Comment: After copying all the jars from this [github repo](https://github.com/rrasmo/owlsrunner) it seems work now, the maven repository is down, so there is no other solution to get all the jars dependency, I'm experiencing the most painful java/maven workflow ever ! is there any alternative the `owls-api` to execute and compose owls web services ?

Comment: A question like "Is there any alternative to this buggy library to work with owls files?" may be off topic, since "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".  However, if you can list some of the alternatives you're willing to consider, this might not be too hard.  E.g., retrieving all the services with a SPARQL query is pretty easy, and it's probably not too hard to get them with the OWL-API either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RDF data here isn't all that complex, so it's not too hard to get what you're looking for by using  a SPARQL query. E.g., you can use the following query to get the following results:

```
prefix service: <http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Service.owl#>
select ?service { ?service a service:Service }
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| service                                                            |
======================================================================
| <http://127.0.0.1/services/1.1/BookFinder.owls#TITLE_BOOK_SERVICE> |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to do this a bit more programmatically, it's just listing instances of the class 
`http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Service.owl#Service`, so you could get that class as an OWLClass, and use [getIndividuals](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClass.html#getIndividuals%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology%29%27) to retrieve the set of its instances.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I succeeded to add the `owls-api-3.1` dependency to my project, but I keep get the `NullPointerException` when trying to get the services from the `owls` file as shown in this [example](http://on.cs.unibas.ch/owls-api/documentation.html#Execute) !

Comment: Without seeing **your** code, I can't really offer any help on that.  Otherwise, there are all sorts of possibilities, some of which are pretty trivial (e.g., did you change the filename used in that example?)

Comment: I just executing the exact example code, But it works well by downloading all the jars dependencies from this [project](https://github.com/rrasmo/owlsrunner), but I don't want to work with jars dependencies (without maven).

Comment: I pushed all the code in a [github repository](https://github.com/tarrsalah/owls-example.git), waiting for your feedback.

Comment: That code doesn't look like it's trying to print any list of services, though.  It'd be better to update your question with additional information then to hope that people see it in the comments on an answer.

Comment: You are right @Joshua it was trying with an `owls 1.1` file, question updated (problem resolved ), thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see that there's an update to the question linking the github, but what's still not working?  Or is everything OK now?

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I don't really think that we found a resolution, though. If this answer solved the problem (I'm not sure whether it did or not), then you might [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).   Otherwise, you might simply delete it, since it seems that "while similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers," which is one of the close reasons.